# how to join four table to display specific data

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

i am having some trouble to JOIN tables. I have four tables

### 'equipment' table

```
equipment_id   equipment_name
-----------    --------------
1              Motor Cycle
2              Private Car
```

=================================

this is my project table

---

```
project_id    project_name
----------    ------------
1              xyz trading 
2              abc private ltd
```

================================

this is rental table

---

```
rental_id      project_id    equipment_id   Rental_date
---------------------------------------------------------
1                 2                 1         12/10/2018
2                 2                2          15/09/2018
3                 1                2          20/10/2018
```

this is removal  table

---

```
remove_id      project_id    equipment_id   removal_date
---------------------------------------------------------
1                 2                 1         null
2                 2                2         14/10/18

these are my table, now i want to display data of single equipment (eg: equipment no 2) in which project this equipment ran, when was the rental date and when was the removal date from a project.
```

I want to display like this.. (using Codeigniter)

Log of equipment 2

=======

```
    SN   Project Name      Rental date       Removal date
    ---  ------------      -----------       ------------
    1    ABC pvt Ltd        15/09/2018       14/10/2018
    2    xyz trading        20/10/2018         Null
```

Controller passes  to Model

```
$data['eqipment_details']=$this->Equipment_model->getLog($equipment_id);
```

Please help me with the query

Comment: Which column and table is "SN" coming from?

Comment: SN just to count the result, using $count=1;  $count=$count+1; in view

Comment: i used this query in my model, which i know is not correct 

public function getLog($equipment_id=0)
        {
  return $this->db->select( '*' )
                                ->from(' rental AS r ')
                                ->join('equipment AS e', 'e.eq_id = r.eq_id' )
                                ->join('removal AS m', 'm.eq_id = e.eq_id')
                                    ->join('project AS p', 'p.project_id = r.project_id')
                                ->where('r.eq_id', $eq_id)
                                ->get()->result_array();
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to guess what your table names would be, but you should be able to adjust from this:

```
SELECT
(@cnt := @cnt + 1) AS SN,
PROJECT.project_name AS Project Name,
RENTAL.Rental_date AS Rental date,
REMOVAL.removal_date AS Removal date 
FROM 
rental_table RENTAL 
LEFT JOIN project_table PROJECT ON (RENTAL.project_id = PROJECT.id) 
LEFT JOIN equipment_table EQUIPMENT ON (RENTAL.equipment_id = EQUIPMENT.id) 
LEFT JOIN removal_table REMOVAL ON (PROJECT.id = REMOVAL.project_id AND PROJECT.equipment_id = REMOVAL.equipment_id) 
WHERE 
EQUIPMENT.id = 2;
```

I'd highly recommend being consistent with your naming conventions you're mixing camel case and title case with underscores.

Comment: No problems. Could you mark the question as answered, thanks :)